# Video capture doesn't work with all supported caps

Tags: python, linux, opencv, gstreamer, v4l2

I am using Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04 on an NVIDIA Jetson TX2. All software is up to date. The Linux kernel is **4.9.140-tegra**. GStreamer is version **1.14.1**.

I have a UVC Capable webcam that shows the following capabilities and I need to stream with the Y16 ( GRAY16_LE ) format:

```
root@nvidia:/tmp# v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext -d /dev/video1
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'UYVY'
        Name        : UYVY 4:2:2
                Size: Discrete 160x120
                        Interval: Discrete 0.111s (9.000 fps)

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'Y16 '
        Name        : 16-bit Greyscale
                Size: Discrete 160x120
                        Interval: Discrete 0.111s (9.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 160x122
                        Interval: Discrete 0.111s (9.000 fps)

        Index       : 2
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'GREY'
        Name        : 8-bit Greyscale
                Size: Discrete 160x120
                        Interval: Discrete 0.111s (9.000 fps)

        Index       : 3
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'RGBP'
        Name        : 16-bit RGB 5-6-5
                Size: Discrete 160x120
                        Interval: Discrete 0.111s (9.000 fps)

        Index       : 4
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'BGR3'
        Name        : 24-bit BGR 8-8-8
                Size: Discrete 160x120
                        Interval: Discrete 0.111s (9.000 fps)
```

With GStreamer from the command line, I can successfully get the device into the **PLAYING** state with gst-launch in the format I want:

```
root@nvidia:/tmp# gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw,width=160,height=122,format='GRAY16_LE',framerate=9/1 ! fakesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

I am trying to open the device with the GRAY16_LE format with Python OpenCV:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw, format=(string)GRAY16_LE, width=(int)160, height=(int)120, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)9/1 ! appsink")
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

During elevated GStreamer debug, the capabilities are probed and printed below:

```
0:00:00.260383826 15768      0x49a9850 INFO                    v4l2 gstv4l2object.c:4136:gst_v4l2_object_probe_caps:<v4l2src0:src> probed caps: video/x-raw, format=(string)UYVY, width=(int)160, height=(int)120, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)9/1; video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR, width=(int)160, height=(int)120, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)9/1; video/x-raw, format=(string)RGB16, width=(int)160, height=(int)120, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)9/1; video/x-raw, format=(string)GRAY8, width=(int)160, height=(int)120, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)9/1; video/x-raw, format=(string)GRAY16_LE, width=(int)160, height=(int)122, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)9/1; video/x-raw, format=(string)GRAY16_LE, width=(int)160, height=(int)120, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)9/1
```

With GStreamer debug on, the errors are shown as below:

```
0:00:00.260385266 15768      0x4744c00 INFO              GST_STATES gstelement.c:2579:_priv_gst_element_state_changed:<v4l2src0> notifying about state-changed PAUSED to PLAYING (VOID_PENDING pending)
0:00:00.260529393 15768      0x49a9850 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.260531697 15768      0x4744c00 INFO              GST_STATES gstbin.c:2952:gst_bin_change_state_func:<pipeline0> child 'v4l2src0' changed state to 4(PLAYING) successfully
0:00:00.260589009 15768      0x49a9850 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<v4l2src0> error: streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
0:00:00.260660881 15768      0x4744c00 INFO              GST_STATES gstbin.c:2087:gst_bin_get_state_func:<pipeline0> getting state
0:00:00.260748913 15768      0x49a9850 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2145:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<v4l2src0> posting message: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.260762833 15768      0x4744c00 INFO              GST_STATES gstelement.c:2392:gst_element_get_state_func:<pipeline0> waiting for element to commit state
0:00:00.260909520 15768      0x49a9850 INFO        GST_ERROR_SYSTEM gstelement.c:2172:gst_element_message_full_with_details:<v4l2src0> posted error message: Internal data stream error.
0:00:00.261064816 15768      0x4744c00 INFO              GST_STATES gstbin.c:2504:gst_bin_element_set_state:<appsink0> current PAUSED pending VOID_PENDING, desired next READY
0:00:00.261189072 15768      0x49a9850 INFO                    task gsttask.c:316:gst_task_func:<v4l2src0:src> Task going to paused
```

I am using the identical format that the probe returns but the error indicates "format negotiation error". How can I fix this so my frames appear in Python?

Comment: The problem is that appsink cannot accept GRAY16_LE. I don't want to videoconvert to lose and information. Is there a way to get my frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to patch the `cap_gstreamer.cpp` file in the OpenCV 4 sources and then build and install OpenCV again.

At that point, I could capture the frames with `appsink` in the `GRAY16_LE` format.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar objective to yours and I was able de capture the Y16 raw frames using OpenCV without patching the `.cpp`

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"Y16 "))
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False)
```

The frames I get are directly in `uint16` format :)